# Laravel POST request failing

Tags: post, laravel

```php
Route::post('/save', function()
{
    $key = Input::get('key');
    echo $key ; 
});
```

Hi, I have the above route defined and I am trying to make a `POST` request to it. The data I am sending is stored in `key` but I am not getting any values in the route.

Is this the proper way of retrieving `POST` requests values?

I would normally retrieve them via `$_POST['key']` using PHP.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Result of request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. However, you need to remove the leading slash from `/save`.

So, your resultant route will look as follows:

```php
Route::post('save', function()
{
    $key = Input::get('key');
    echo $key ; 
});
```

Comment: I have a problem with post request too. Can you please help. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32113117/post-request-not-working-laravel-5)