# post request not working Laravel 5

Tags: html, post, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

I am trying to submit a form using post method, but it does not seem to be working. I have enabled error debug on but still no error is shown. After submitting the form the same page is loaded without any errors.
This is my route

```
Route::post('/home' , ['as' => 'store-post' , 'uses'=>'FacebookControllers\PostsController@save']);
```

And my form is

```
{!!  Form::open(['route'=>'store-post' , 'class'=>'form'])!!}
                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="textarea"></label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="textarea">What's on your mind?</textarea>
                   </div>
                   <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                         <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                   </div
{!!  Form::close() !!}
```

This is my Controller

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function save(PostsRequests $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        $post = new Post();
        $post->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $post->content =$input;
        $post->user()->associate(1);
        $post->save();

        /*return redirect('home');*/
        return ('something');
    }
}
```

Comment: no body knows the solution :/

Comment: Have you tried to put a breakpoint in App\Exceptions\Handler.php?
`public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }`

Comment: sorry? I do not know how to put a breakpoint as I am not very expert in laravel. I am just a beginner. @JuliaLogvina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching and trying, finally, I found the solution. I was using my own request class and path was not correct so I corrected the path of `PostsRequests` and now it works.